# Non-trivial homotopy, but vanishing homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

I wonder if there are examples of 5-dimensional manifolds with vanishing integral second homology group, but non-vanishing second homotopy group? Or is it impossible by some Hurewicz theorem type of argument? Unfortunately I do not see it.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^2\times S^3$ appears to be such an example.